# What does Guava's Cache do when it hits its maximumSize?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I've been working on a project lately, It's about restricting connections per second.

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .maximumSize(instance.getSettings().getInt("CONNECTION-PER-SEC"))
        .build();
```

So the system works like, When a player joins the server, the player will be added to the cache, which expires every 1 second. If cache has reached its limit of connections per second, it blocks all connections. Please tell me how to run code when the cache is full instead of removing the oldest element from the cache (https://www.baeldung.com/guava-cache#1-eviction-by-size). Thank you.

I've tried to mess around with the API but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is Guava's [RateLimiter](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html)?

Comment: @BenManes can you give me a code example of RateLimiter pleasE?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter) might help.